# WPF Anchor right-most column to right of grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hey I am trying to get my right-most column to be anchored to the right side of the grid.
I do not mind if the last column is set to a fixed width as the image it contains is a set width.

Here is the "remove button" column and it is the last column in my grid. 
Here is what it looks like:
http://postimg.org/image/lmj2uo6nt/

```
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Remove" Width="Auto">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Command="Delete">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding fileDeleteImageLocation}"  />
                                            <Button.Template>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Button.Template>
                                        </Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>

                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set one of your column width to * which will allocate the remaining space to that column. This will put your last column on the far right.

Comment: is there anyway to ensure it has a minimum width?